# QMake not matching regex for distro detection

Tags: regex, qt, qmake

I have a C++ project using QMake.  I'm trying to set some compiler options based on a simple test of which Linux distro is running, but the test does not pass.  My qmake file contains:

```
OSDISTRO = $$(cat /proc/version)
contains(OSDISTRO, "Ubuntu"): {
  message(Found ubuntu)
}
```

I tested the regex from the command line and it works!

```
cat /proc/version | pcregrep "Ubuntu"
Linux version 4.18.0-20-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-020) (gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)) #21~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 8 08:43:37 UTC 2019
```

Is there something special about the regex syntax in qmake?  Any reason why this isn't working?

Comment: what is the output of  `message($$OSDISTRO)`? Also, your code throws me a syntax error: `Missing ) terminator [found  ]`. the right thing should be `OSDISTRO = $$cat(/proc/version)` but this returns "" and I think it's per permissions

Comment: Another possible option is `OSDISTRO = $$system(cat /proc/version)`.  QMake version 3.1

Comment: I got it to work by changing to OS command to "cat /proc/version | grep -i "ubuntu" | wc -l)" and the checking for contains 1.  That seems like an unnecessary workaround.  I would like to know why the one above doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

For the ***RegEx:***

This works for me:

```
OSDISTRO = $$system(cat /proc/version)
contains(OSDISTRO, .*Ubuntu.*){
  message("Found Ubuntu")
}
```

***Note:***
The match is case sensitive.

You can use `.*[uU]buntu.*` for example to match `ubuntu` and `Ubuntu`.

***Explanation*** why your solution does not work:

The `QMake` function `contains` works with ***lists*** of values.

So, the execution of you solution will be like this:

1) First instruction `OSDISTRO = $$(cat /proc/version)`:

- `QMake` will execute `$$system(cat /proc/version)`.
- Then the result is splitted (by space as separator) to list of values. `OSDISTRO` will contain this list.

Assuming that the result is as yours. The result of the first instruction is like this: 
`OSDISTRO = "Linux" "version" "4.18.0-20-generic"...`.

2) Second instruction `contains(OSDISTRO, "Ubuntu") : message(Found ubuntu)`:

- `QMake` will search if the variable `OSDISTRO` contains the value `Ubuntu` and display the message `Found ubuntu` if success.

Here in your case, `QMake` will never find `Ubuntu`, cause the value which contains it is like this `(Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)` and `QMake` search only the value `Ubuntu`.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I found a bug report on Qt that said the contains second argument is NOT a regex.  This is interesting...

Comment: Maybe, but i tested it in `QMake version 3.1` it works fine.

Comment: FYI qmake has a built-in cat function, so first line could read `OSDISTRO = $$cat(/proc/version)"`.
Out of interest, is using `/etc/issue` instead same / better / worse?